# How to create DESeqDataSetFromMatrix from 2 vectors of numbers?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two datasets, each having the form:

```
Gene1Name, 234
Gene2Name, 445
Gene3Name, 23
...
GeneNName, 554
```

The gene names are identical for each of the 2 datasets. The numbers on the second column are the expression counts for the corresponding gene.

I want to perform a differential gene expression analysis on these datasets. For that, I am using a [DESeq](http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#quick-start) library.

To use the DESeq function one needs to create an object

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=data, colData=meta, design=~sampletype)
```

For my case, **what** needs to be passed as arguments into 
the `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix` function?

Comment: So those data sets, you've mentioned, are different treatments?

Comment: @utubun, Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if you'll try to follow this simple example, it might, at least, help you to solve your real problem.

We have to start from dummy data set preparation (please read [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)):

#### Make a `treatment` data set:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(56154455)

treatment <- data.frame(
  geneName = LETTERS,
  cts      = sample(0:1000, 26)
)

head(treatment)

#   geneName cts
# 1        A 834
# 2        B 860
# 3        C 950
# 4        D 302
# 5        E 979
# 6        F 159
```

#### Make a `control` data set:

```
set.seed(56154455)

control   <- treatment[sample(1:26, 26), ]
control[, 1] <- treatment[, 1]

head(control)

#    geneName cts
# 3         A 950
# 23        B  41
# 15        C 889
# 20        D 629
# 14        E 398
# 4         F 302
```

#### Join both `treatment` and `control` by `geneName`

```
cts <- full_join(treatment, control, by = 'geneName') %>%
  rename('treatment' = cts.x, 'control' = cts.y) %>%
  column_to_rownames('geneName') %>%
  as.matrix

head(cts)

#   treatment control
# A       331     737
# B       914     676
# C       161     161
# D       592     769
# E       946      74
# F       813     314
```

#### Prepare your `coldata` table

Remember, this is just a *dummy* example, so your *real* `coldata`, might include any number of columns, which reflects the *design of your experiment*. However, the number of rows in your `coldata`, *has to be* equal to the number of columns in your experimental data (here it is `cts`). Please read the [documentation for SummarizedExperiment](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/SummarizedExperiment/inst/doc/SummarizedExperiment.html) class, where you can find detailed explanation. Another great resource is the [Rafa's book](https://leanpub.com/dataanalysisforthelifesciences)

```
coldata <- matrix(c("DMSO", "1xPBS"), dimnames = list(colnames(cts), 'treatment'))

coldata

#        treatment
# treatment "DMSO"   
# control   "1xPBS"
```

#### Finally, create your `DESeqDataSet`:

```
dds <- DESeq2::DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(
  countData = cts, 
  colData   = coldata, 
  design    = ~treatment
  )
```

Where:

- `countData` is your experimental data, prepared as above;
- `colData`   is your `coldata` matrix, with experimental metadata;
- `~treatment` is the formula, describing the *experimental model* you test in your experiment. It could be anything like `~ treatment + sex * age` etc.

☠

```
dds

# class: DESeqDataSet 
# dim: 26 2 
# metadata(1): version
# assays(1): counts
# rownames(26): A B ... Y Z
# rowData names(0):
# colnames(2): treatment control
# colData names(1): treatment
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concatenate the two vectors and put it into a matrix.

Since you said your two datasets contain two column, I assume first is gene name, second is count.  You also mentioned that the names are the same.  So you can do this:

```
data <- cbind(x1[,2], x2[,2])
rownames(data) <- x1[,1]
colnames(data) <- c("sample1", "sample2")

meta <- data.frame(sampletype = c("A", "B"))

dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=data, colData=meta, design=~sampletype)
```

Comment: And what do you pass as `meta` as well as `sampletype`?

Comment: See updated answer.  You should check out the vignette for DESeq2, I think it's a very good tutorial.